# Не показывает GIF в Qlabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qmovie

Прошу помочь. Создаю программу для отображения *GIF* на PyQt5 (Qt Designer). Но программа  не отображает *GIF*.

Программа не выдает ошибку.

OS **`Windows 10`** Домашняя 2004 19041.928 
**`Python 3.9.5`** 
**`PyQT '5.15.4'`**

Код

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(250, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # create label
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 25, 200, 200))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        # add label to main window
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        # set qmovie as label
        self.movie = QMovie("1.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кроме того, что я вам уже написал, попробуйте скопировать и запустить некоторые ответы из вопросов аналогичной тематики: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1193771 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177777 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130154/

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо вам. Ошибка была в том что плагин imageformats не было видно для pyqt5

Comment: Lal Qarğa что вы исправили, объясните лучше.

Comment: @S.Nick Добрый день. при подключении библиотеки pyqt5 (pip install pyqt5) плагины загружаются в папку "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins". При этом, python.exe находится в папке \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39. Как я понял, в таком случае python.exe "не видит" плагины pyqt5. Из за этого программа pyqt5 либо выдает ошибки либо работает некорректно. Как вариант, необходимо добавить папки с плагинами в папку где находится сам python.exe. Аналогичная ошибка : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1_RHep2mVU

Answer (score 0):

У меня ваш пример работает. У вас либо битая гифка, либо указан неверно путь к гифке, либо добавьте

```
self.movie.setScaledSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
```

> void QMovie::setScaledSize(const QSize &size)
>
> Устанавливает масштабированный размер кадра по размеру.

и  вам не рекомендую изменять код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(250, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # create label
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 25, 200, 200))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        # add label to main window
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        # set qmovie as label          
        self.movie = QMovie("img/Fo2BxBK.gif")
        
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))               # +++
                
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробовал изменить gif файл, добавил указанный код, изменил путь к файл. Не помогло. Может причина в самом pyqt5?

Comment: @LalQarğa Покажите как вы указываете путь к гифке и где она у вас находится. 
`self.movie = QMovie("D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/Fo2BxBK.gif")` - так пробовали ?  
Покажите как вы запускаете приложение и откуда. 
Я рекомендую выполнить скрипт в терминале/CMD.

Comment: файл py и gif находятся на одном и то же папке. путь файла py: C:\Users\Джавад\Desktop\project\резерв\v9\test.py    путь к файл gif: C:\Users\Джавад\Desktop\project\резерв\v9\giphy.gif

Comment: self.movie = QMovie("C:/Users/Джавад/Desktop/project/резерв/v9/giphy.gif")

Comment: запустил через терминал. тоже не помогло. а так до этого открыл через python.exe (Python3.9)

Comment: @LalQarğa создайте новый каталог, попроще, без кириллицы. Положите туда скрипт и гифку. Зайдите в этот каталог и запустите `python main.py`

Comment: Пробовал. добавил в папку C:\Users\Public\Documents\v9 и пробовал открыть. не отображает gif. Прошу уточнить, может ли повлиять на это версия python? так как у меня стоит версия 3.9 питона

Comment: @LalQarğa создайте новый каталог, попроще, без кириллицы, `os.mkdir("c://test")`. Положите туда скрипт `main.py` и гифку `1.gif`. Зайдите в этот каталог и запустите `python main.py`. Строку оставьте так:  `self.movie = QMovie("1.gif")`

Comment: Извините за то что вас беспокою))) Сделал. тоже не помогает

Comment: @LalQarğa напишите в теле вопроса какая у вас ОС, какая версия Python, какая версия PyQt. Может кто-то проверит имея аналогичные исходные данные.